# How many times is this that you've broken your promise. <Is this grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

How many times is this that you've broken your promise? I am reasonably sure that "How many times does this make it that you've broken your promise?" is correct. However, both sound fine to me and I can't be sure that the former is grammatically correct.

Comment: There is a style of speaking where your title line would be used (possibly by your mother), and it is arguably correct from a grammatical standpoint.  Purists would object, no doubt.

Comment: "How many times is **it** that you've broken your promise?" Or more likely, the granny implied "How many ***-eth** time is this that you've broken your promise?" :D Check with her.

Answer (score 1):

Both your attempts seem rather clumsy. The original edit had the phrase "including this time" implying that the promise has been recently broken, again.

You could ask the question

> How many times have you broken your promise now?

which includes the most recent.

Comment: Ahhhh Nice. Thanks.  Clumsy or not, I'm still wondering if they're grammatically OK. But your solution is excellent and its what I needed.

Comment: @RossTulloch I believe both your suggestions are grammatically correct.